# Flutter null safety issues, unable to compile

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am having the following errors when building my FLUTTER WEB application:

```
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies don't support null safety:

 - package:html2md
 - package:html
 - package:csslib

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/easy_web_view-1.4.0-nullsafety/lib/src/web.dart:61:5: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'EasyWebView' which excludes null.
 - 'EasyWebView' is from 'package:easy_web_view/src/web.dart' ('../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/easy_web_view-1.4.0-nullsafety/lib/src/web.dart').
    widget?.onLoaded();
    ^ ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/easy_web_view-1.4.0-nullsafety/lib/src/web.dart:66:15: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'EasyWebView' which excludes null.
 - 'EasyWebView' is from 'package:easy_web_view/src/web.dart' ('../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/easy_web_view-1.4.0-nullsafety/lib/src/web.dart').
          if (widget?.onLoaded != null) {
              ^ ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/easy_web_view-1.4.0-nullsafety/lib/src/web.dart:95:14: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'EasyWebView' which excludes null.
 - 'EasyWebView' is from 'package:easy_web_view/src/web.dart' ('../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/easy_web_view-1.4.0-nullsafety/lib/src/web.dart').
      width: widget?.width,
             ^ ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/easy_web_view-1.4.0-nullsafety/lib/src/web.dart:96:15: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'EasyWebView' which excludes null.
 - 'EasyWebView' is from 'package:easy_web_view/src/web.dart' ('../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/easy_web_view-1.4.0-nullsafety/lib/src/web.dart').
      height: widget?.height,
              ^ ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/easy_web_view-1.4.0-nullsafety/lib/src/web.dart:124:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'EasyWebView' which excludes null.
 - 'EasyWebView' is from 'package:easy_web_view/src/web.dart' ('../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/easy_web_view-1.4.0-nullsafety/lib/src/web.dart').
              key: widget?.key,
                   ^ Unhandled exception: Bad state: Unsupported Null Safety mode NonNullableByDefaultCompiledMode.Invalid, in null.
#0      ProgramCompiler.emitModule (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:435:9)
#1      JavaScriptBundler.compile (package:frontend_server/src/javascript_bundle.dart:144:33)
#2      FrontendCompiler.writeJavascriptBundle (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:632:20) <asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:545:9) <asynchronous suspension>
#4      listenAndCompile.<anonymous closure> (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:1105:11) <asynchronous suspension> Finished with error: the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly. Failed to compile application.
```

The following are my dependencies:

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^0.13.1
  json_annotation: ^4.0.1
  provider: ^5.0.0
  google_fonts: ^2.0.0
  vibration: ^1.7.4-nullsafety.0 #^1.7.4
  firebase_core: ^1.0.2
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.2
  easy_web_view: ^1.4.0-nullsafety #easy_web_view: ^1.3.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  uuid: ^3.0.2
  url_launcher: ^6.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

`easy_web_view: ^1.4.0-nullsafety` uses the package `html2md` in version 0.5.1, that does not fully support null safety.

`html2md` is available in version 1.0.0 that does support null safety, but there was no update to `easy_web_view` that uses this new version.

You will have to wait for the maintainer of `easy_web_view` to create an updated version or you can help and branch it and do it yourself.

Comment: @Damandroid probably create a issue in https://github.com/rodydavis/easy_web_view about it

Comment: I will update it soon! Please submit a PR